# Can I constrain my neurons in a neural network in according to the orders of the input?

Tags: neural-networks, machine-learning, deep-learning, keras

I'm working with data that is ranked. So the inputs are 1,2,3 etc. This means the smaller numbers (ranks) are preferred to the larger ones. Hence the order is important. I want to estimate a number using regression; however, with the constraint that the order of the numbers must be monotonic non-linear.

Imagine the following input table:

```
1, 2
2, 3
3, 1
```

For instance, if the output is 1000 for each input, then the estimation could be:

```
1 * (800) + 2 * (100) = 1000
2 * (300) + 3 * (60) = 780
3 * (150) + 1 * (400) = 850
```

Evidently, the estimated Xs are monotonic non-linear decreasing.
For the first column: 1 -> 800, 2 -> 600 (2x300), 3 -> 450 (3x150)
for the second columns: 1 -> 400, 2 -> 200 (2x100), 3-> 180 (2x60)

So here's the question. Can I ensure my model (neural network) enforces the given constraint? I am using Keras.

Comment: hi, do you mean that you want a control on the output of the network w.r.t the order of the inputs you put in?

Comment: Do you think you could pre-process the inputs so that they come in order?

Comment: No. I mean to put a constraint when finding the weights (or preferably neuron) that the less value the input neuron has the more values should be found to solve the regression problem. Pre-processing is not a bad idea, but the problem is that I have thousands of features that all describe an order for an input row.